# MongoDB: Aggregation - Numbering

Tags: mongodb

I have an array of elements that are unwound. I want to project the field "number" to each unwound element that is incremented by 1 for each element. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that is not possible with aggregation framework in current stable versions of mongodb as says at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663517/how-to-project-array-index-after-unwinding-an-array-with-mongodb-aggregation-fra). But, [from version 3.1.8](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4588) it seems to be possible with db.command:

```
db.runCommand({ aggregate:"c", pipeline:[
    { $unwind: { path: "$arrayField", includeArrayIndex: boolean }}
]});
```